# SQL - Generate 1st day of Month From a Start and End date Range

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, ssms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTkFG.png)How do we generate dates having 1st day of the month for a give Start and end date as variables
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTkFG.png)
the image shows April to dec as start and end dates

Comment: Please post sample data as text, not an image.  Can you give some sample inputs and what the expected outputs are?

Comment: yes i have added it

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are doing, you might want to create a calendar table

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? For example `DECLARE @StartDate DATE`

Comment: There are several ways. What about all the answers you read when you searched "Get first day of month in SQL" didn't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2021-04-01', @EndDate DATE  = '2021-12-01';

WITH CTE_dates AS
  ( SELECT @StartDate AS PeriodDates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,PeriodDates)
    FROM CTE_dates 
    WHERE PeriodDates < @EndDate
  )
SELECT PeriodDates FROM CTE_dates
GO
```

[image]

Comment: awesome thnks this is wht i wanted

Comment: For those who might stumble on this answer like me, but who are using Google BigQuery, here is a supported version of the suggested answer from @NiharikaMoola-MT


    `DECLARE StartDate,EndDate DATE;
    SET (StartDate, EndDate) = ('2021-04-01', '2021-12-01');
    
    WITH RECURSIVE dates AS (SELECT StartDate as day --Initial Subquery
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT date_add(day, INTERVAL 1 Month) FROM dates WHERE day < EndDate) -- Recursive Subquery
    SELECT * FROM dates order by day asc;`

Comment: @c.malcolmRichard if this is what you wanted, then please accept this as the correct answer.