# From one record to more records that represent mm/yyyy

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Let's say that we have this table

| Employee | EmploymentStarted | EmploymentEnded |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sara | 20210115 | 20210715 |
| Lora | 20210215 | 20210815 |
| Viki | 20210515 | 20210615 |

Now what I need is a table that we can see all the employees that we had each month. For example, Sara started on January 15th 2021 and she left the company on July 15th 2021. This means that she has been with us during January, February, March, April, May, June and July.

The result table should look like this:

| Month | Year | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| January | 2021 | Sara |
| February | 2021 | Sara |
| February | 2021 | Lora |
| March | 2021 | Sara |
| March | 2021 | Lora |
| April | 2021 | Sara |
| April | 2021 | Lora |
| May | 2021 | Sara |
| May | 2021 | Lora |
| May | 2021 | Viki |
| June | 2021 | Sara |
| June | 2021 | Lora |
| June | 2021 | Viki |
| July | 2021 | Sara |
| July | 2021 | Lora |
| August | 2021 | Lora |

How can I get a table like this in SQL?

I tried a group by, but it does not seem to be the right way to do it

Comment: A [calendar table](https://gist.github.com/gavincampbell/4a4d4aa581038c261d89eddddfcaf45c) would help you out a lot. You can join from this calendar table to your data and generate the output you are wanting. Calendar tables are one of the first things I build in a new database because they solve so many problems. `SELECT DISTINCT ct.MonthName, ct.[year], yt.Employee FROM calendartable ct INNER JOIN yourtable yt ON ct.date BETWEEN yt.EmployementStarted and yt.EmploymentEnded` would get you in the ballpark.

Comment: you can generate date series with CTEs https://stackoverflow.com/a/71323142/5193536

Comment: I really recommend a Tally (which can be created with CTEs) over the rCTE solution demonstrated there, @nbk . rCTEs are slower than a tally, and they become *significantly* slower with larger data sets and/or ranges.

Comment: JNevill's comment did exactly what I wanted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to find out in practice how much performance decreases when using recursion. In this case calendarTable contain less about 12 records per year. Most part of query cost is **JOIN** to Employee (staff) table.

```
with FromTo as (
  select min(EmploymentStarted) fromDt, eomonth(max(EmploymentEnded)) toDt
  from staff
  )
--,FromTo as(select fromDt=@fromDt,toDt=@toDt)
,rdT as (
  select 1 n,fromDt bM,eomonth(fromDt) eM
        ,fromDt, toDt
  from FromTo
  union all
  select n+1 n,dateadd(day,1,eM) bM,eomonth(dateadd(month,1,bM)) eM
        ,fromDt,toDt
  from rdT where dateadd(month,1,bM)<toDt
)
select month(bM) as 'Month',year(bM) as 'Year',Employee  --* 
from rdT left join staff s on s.EmploymentEnded>=bM and s.EmploymentStarted<=eM
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lcwrHF3j)